# MongoDB $or query with index

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need make a query with indice at the mongodb, I will show below a minimal case example of my real case.

I have following collection with flowing data:

```
devsrv(mongod-3.0.4) test> db.teste.find()
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324c341aaa4b930ef3b92"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 1
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324c941aaa4b930ef3b93"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324cd41aaa4b930ef3b94"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 3
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324d141aaa4b930ef3b95"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 4
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324d541aaa4b930ef3b96"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 5
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324da41aaa4b930ef3b97"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 6
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324df41aaa4b930ef3b98"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 7
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324e441aaa4b930ef3b99"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": 8
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324f341aaa4b930ef3b9a"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": ""
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324f641aaa4b930ef3b9b"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": " "
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b324fc41aaa4b930ef3b9c"),
  "a": 1,
  "b": null
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b3250341aaa4b930ef3b9d"),
  "a": 1
}
{
  "_id": ObjectId("57b46ace41aaa4b930ef3b9e"),
  "a": 2
}
```

And I have the following indexes:

```
devsrv(mongod-3.0.4) test> db.teste.getIndexes()
[
  {
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
      "_id": 1
    },
    "name": "_id_",
    "ns": "test.teste"
  },
  {
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
      "a": 1,
      "b": 1
    },
    "name": "a_1_b_1",
    "ns": "test.teste"
  },
  {
    "v": 1,
    "key": {
      "b": 1
    },
    "name": "b_1",
    "ns": "test.teste"
  }
]
```

And I need make a query equal this:

```
devsrv(mongod-3.0.4) test> db.teste.find({$or:[{"b":null},{"b":""},{"b":" "},{"b":{$lt:3}}],"a":1}).explain("executionStats")
{
  "queryPlanner": {
    "plannerVersion": 1,
    "namespace": "test.teste",
    "indexFilterSet": false,
    "parsedQuery": {
      "$and": [
        {
          "$or": [
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": null
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": " "
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$lt": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "a": {
            "$eq": 1
          }
        }
      ]
    },
    "winningPlan": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "filter": {
        "a": {
          "$eq": 1
        }
      },
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "filter": {
          "$or": [
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": null
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": " "
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$lt": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "IXSCAN",
          "keyPattern": {
            "b": 1
          },
          "indexName": "b_1",
          "isMultiKey": false,
          "direction": "forward",
          "indexBounds": {
            "b": [
              "[null, null]",
              "[-inf.0, 3.0)",
              "[\"\", \"\"]",
              "[\" \", \" \"]"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "rejectedPlans": [
      {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "filter": {
          "$or": [
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": null
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": " "
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$lt": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "IXSCAN",
          "keyPattern": {
            "a": 1,
            "b": 1
          },
          "indexName": "a_1_b_1",
          "isMultiKey": false,
          "direction": "forward",
          "indexBounds": {
            "a": [
              "[1.0, 1.0]"
            ],
            "b": [
              "[MinKey, MaxKey]"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "executionStats": {
    "executionSuccess": true,
    "nReturned": 6,
    "executionTimeMillis": 0,
    "totalKeysExamined": 8,
    "totalDocsExamined": 14,
    "executionStages": {
      "stage": "FETCH",
      "filter": {
        "a": {
          "$eq": 1
        }
      },
      "nReturned": 6,
      "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
      "works": 10,
      "advanced": 6,
      "needTime": 2,
      "needFetch": 0,
      "saveState": 0,
      "restoreState": 0,
      "isEOF": 1,
      "invalidates": 0,
      "docsExamined": 7,
      "alreadyHasObj": 7,
      "inputStage": {
        "stage": "FETCH",
        "filter": {
          "$or": [
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": null
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": ""
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$eq": " "
              }
            },
            {
              "b": {
                "$lt": 3
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "nReturned": 7,
        "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
        "works": 8,
        "advanced": 7,
        "needTime": 1,
        "needFetch": 0,
        "saveState": 0,
        "restoreState": 0,
        "isEOF": 1,
        "invalidates": 0,
        "docsExamined": 7,
        "alreadyHasObj": 0,
        "inputStage": {
          "stage": "IXSCAN",
          "nReturned": 7,
          "executionTimeMillisEstimate": 0,
          "works": 8,
          "advanced": 7,
          "needTime": 1,
          "needFetch": 0,
          "saveState": 0,
          "restoreState": 0,
          "isEOF": 1,
          "invalidates": 0,
          "keyPattern": {
            "b": 1
          },
          "indexName": "b_1",
          "isMultiKey": false,
          "direction": "forward",
          "indexBounds": {
            "b": [
              "[null, null]",
              "[-inf.0, 3.0)",
              "[\"\", \"\"]",
              "[\" \", \" \"]"
            ]
          },
          "keysExamined": 8,
          "dupsTested": 0,
          "dupsDropped": 0,
          "seenInvalidated": 0,
          "matchTested": 0
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "serverInfo": {
    "host": "devsrv",
    "port": 27017,
    "version": "3.0.4",
    "gitVersion": "0481c958daeb2969800511e7475dc66986fa9ed5"
  },
  "ok": 1
}
```

But MongoDB isn't using the two indexes together.

Comment: Does anyone know tell me a way to force the mongo to use two indexes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each `$or` term is effectively a separate query, so it helps to structure your query so that each term aligns with the index you're hoping to use. In this case that means moving the `a: 1` part inside of each `$or` term:

```
db.teste.find({
  $or:[
    {a: 1, b: null},
    {a: 1, b: ""},
    {a: 1, b: " "},
    {a: 1, b: {$lt: 3}}
  ]}).explain('executionStats')
```

The explain output shows that the `a_1_b_1` is used for this query.

But you can simplify this a bit more by using `$in` to combine the first three terms into one:

```
db.teste.find({
  $or:[
    {a: 1, b: {$in: [null, "", " "]}},
    {a: 1, b: {$lt: 3}}
  ]}).explain('executionStats')
```

This is also able to use the `a_1_b_1` index.

Comment: i don't to use twice the parameter  a, in real case this parameter is from a query dinamic

Answer (score 0):

The code is

```
db.teste.explain("executionStats").find({a: 1,
                                         $or:[{b: null},
                                              {b: ""},
                                              {b: " "},
                                              {b: {$lt:3}}]
                                        }).hint({a: 1, b: 1})
```

Be careful with the [hint](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.hint/) command as the query optimizer chooses the most efficient query by measuring actual performance of the query with every suitable index.

Comment: @DimiAntoniVargas It's a good practice to accept the answers that solve your problem :-)